# determining the right T for T.TryParse while reading a stream

Tags: c#

I have a method that Inputs a text file from passed string, have to check whether the passed type's TryParse is OK with read strings from stream, and then adds items to passed combobox

I tried to do this but stuck at how to pass the type and then check TryParse.

```
private void Input(string file, ComboBox cb, /* object passedType */)
        {
            if (File.Exists(c + "recent_IPs.txt"))
            {
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(c + "recent_IPs.txt", FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string read = reader.ReadLine();
                    /* passedType t; */
                    if (/* passedType.TryParse(read, out t) */)
                    {
                        cb.Items.Add(read);
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
                stream.Close();

                if (cb.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: By the way the "c" in

```
...
if (File.Exists(c + "recent_IPs.txt"))
...
```

is

```
string c = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: Read yourself into Generics (type T).

Comment: Use Path.Combine() instead of string concatenation to create the path to the recent_IPs.txt file.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels Can we do something on method's parameters like: string file = Path.Combine(c + file) :: I mean can we make file parameter get ready for method before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do this with reflection:

- Change `passedType` to be of type `Type`
- Find the right method using `Type.GetMethod` or `Type.GetMethods`, noting that the method may be overloaded
- Call the method

Alternatively, if possible, change the method to accept a delegate:

```
private void Input(string file, ComboBox cb, Func<string, bool> validator)
```

then just call the delegate. You can then use:

```
Input(file, cb, text => { int dummy; return int.TryParse(text, out dummy); });
```

(etc)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get how to do this with 1st method, but I've done it with 2nd. Could you give more details about 1st? I'm wondering how to do this with it.

Comment: @haxxoromer: Well which bit do you not understand? Reflection is a big topic.

Comment: Okay, I get 1st line (Lol), I don't know what's 2nd and 3rd lines about... Also don't know much about reflection